# How to attach one volume to multiple instances in EUCALYPTUS amazon aws cloud server

Tags: amazon-web-services, eucalyptus

[Eucalyptus]

I have a EBS volume created, and i will have to attach it to all other running instances. Currently AWS EBS volume attaches to only one running instances at a time.

So, Are there any other volume types which actually attaches one volume to multiple instances? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not attach one EBS Volume to multiple instances at the same time in Eucalyptus. You can only attach to one instance, then detach the volume and attach to another instance.

Answer (score 2):

A Better approach would be to use AWS EFS. It's Network File Sharing on Steroids (provided by AWS, obviously). You can share a volume between multiple instances. [AWS EFS - Elastic File System](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using a Eucalyptus console. When i create volume, the default file system is EBS. Is there any way to achieve EFS through Eucalyptus console or euca2ool command line?

Comment: I have limited knowledge of Eucalyptus. As far as I have checked, it's not possible with Eucalyptus console or euca2ool command line. Another option apart from using AWS EFS would be manually implementing Linux NFS.